# google apps and phpmail()

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email, gmail

I've setup a intranet wiki/svn/trac server and would like to get the email settings working.
I know how to do it on our hosting provider through cpanel with mxrecords, blah, blah, blah.

Could anyone point me in the right direction for doing it on a local server?
In case it matters, we're running ubuntu 8.04 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to make this happen is to configure your Ubuntu server as a local mail server and forward everything to your google apps server. The configure phpmail to use local smtp server for sending/recieving mail.

Please refer to this question:

[How to Setup Ubuntu Mail Server with Google Apps?](https://serverfault.com/questions/54069/how-to-setup-ubuntu-mail-server-with-google-apps)

Comment: I think google has a limit of 500 emails per day outgoing(i think).. so if you are using it for a website registration etc, you may run out..