# Using ubuntu server for google apps email or windows live domains

Tags: ubuntu, email-server, g-suite, mail-forwarding

I want to know how to set up an Ubuntu server so as to use google apps to handle email.

I searched around and found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/54069/how-to-setup-ubuntu-mail-server-with-google-apps) but the problem with this seems to be that while I'm able to send email from google apps, I can't recieve any email that I send to any address on my domain.
Is there any forwarding that has to be set up?

Also is it possible to use windows live domains instead.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Windows Live Domains. But I have used/use Google Apps.

You use a Google Apps setup just like a GMail setup. To receive mail you should be using the webmail interface or a mail user agent that supports GMail: (that means IMAP or POP). Thunderbird's my desktop client of choice, and it has support for adding a GMail account with a few pretty little customizations IIRC, right out of the box.

If you specifically want a command-line mail client, you'll need something that can access GMail via either [IMAP](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=75725) or [POP](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13273). I think [alpine](http://www.washington.edu/alpine/) works [(here are instructions)](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~csadmin/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_Pine_(Alpine)_for_IMAP_Gmail), but can't really give you many choices. I only use command line mail clients for local logging mail, not external "real" email.

The question you linked describes sending mail (that's what SMTP is for). In my case, I'd use a setup like that so system daemons or personal programs could easily send email. It wouldn't be for personal email use.

Comment: Thats not what i mean,
The problem that i face is that when I send mail from another email address to an email address at my domain, it never gets delivered. That is i can send email with google apps but not receive mail.

Comment: If the mail does not show up in your webmail box, you do have a problem. But with Google Apps the mail never touches your Ubuntu server and everything to do with it is irrelevant. You set up a series of `MX` records in your DNS telling the world to deliver mail to Google's servers. Check those records. Otherwise, check your Google Apps accounts to verify that the account is valid and set to receive mail.

Comment: I can't set up the MX records, I don't have access to a web based interface. Can I some how set the MX records using the command line. I have root access to the server with ssh.

Comment: It has been some time and the google apps page says "We are checking MX records for your domain. This may take 48 hours to complete".

Comment: um. well. if you don't set up the `MX` records, there's not a heckuva lot for mail to do. And I have no idea how you in particular need to do that... I run a BIND server. If you do that, just edit the zone. If you have your DNS hosted somewhere, talk to them.